# What happened to Jeff Tracy's wife?

Tags: thunderbirds

From [*Thunderbirds* wiki](http://thunderbirds.wikia.com/wiki/Jeff_Tracy) we get this:

> After Maureen's tragic death...

But having seen *every* episode multiple times, there simply is no reference to his wife, or him even having a wife.  Based on Jeff's personality, I think it likely that he did in fact have a wife, so what happened to her?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the Thunderbirds Wiki calls her Maureen, but other sources disagree with the name.  All do, however, agree she died.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeff_Tracy), we learn there are multiple causes explained for her death:

> His wife died prematurely, commonly accepted to have been due to complications with the birth on 12 March 2044 of her youngest son, Alan. A non-canonical 1993 comic strip has a different explanation [She and Jeff's father died in an avalanche], while a novel published in 2008 had her pass away as a result of a road accident.

Summary

- She died after complications in Alan's birth
- She passed away in a road accident
- Both his wife and father died in an avalanche

But [here](http://thunderbirdscentral.tikatu.com/faqsTV.shtml#lucille) we are told his wife's name was actually Lucille (Lucy), although providing the reasons of an avalanche or complications at Alan's birth.

It would seem most likely that either of the above are possible, although the *most* likely would be the avalanche, hence the inspiration for creating International Rescue, which is another question altogether!

Answer (score 0):

The wiki articles i've read say her name is Lucille (Lucy) and that she and Jeff's father died in an avalanche. It wasn't what motivated him to start IR, but was a factor. A comic strip shows that an plane crash that killed 80 people, and a lack of specialist equipment was the driving force behind Jeff's decision to start International rescue, and 2 years later it was formed.

Comment: Can those wiki articles provide a source? If so, please provide the original sources.